# Is the pressure in a pipe equal the pressure in the tank?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, gas

In my example, there is a tank which is holding gas under pressure. Connected to this tank is an output pipe. Assuming the pipe is the same diameter for the entirety of its length, would the pressure within the pipe be equal to that of the pressure in the tank?

Likewise, if a component has a maximum pressure rating, how could one reduce the pressure in the pipe such that the gas flowing into this component doesn't exceed this maximum pressure?

Comment: Is the pipe open so that gas flows out of the tank or is it closed?

Comment: @md2perpe my example would be such that the pipe connects the gas to component, where it is then "used" before being exhausted from the system. An example could be an engine that runs on methane, which is stored in a tank.

Answer (score 1):

The pressure can be reduced by gravity and flow. The pressure at a lower height will be larger than than at a greater height (however, if you're dealing with just a gas, you need a large distance for the difference to be significant). Also, when a fluid under pressure is released, some of the internal energy is converted to velocity, reducing the pressure. So when gas is flowing out of the tank, its pressure will be lower than the gas in the tank.

Comment: This answer is reversed. In a gravity field, pressure at the bottom of an enclosure is *higher* than at the top.

Answer (score 0):

In contemporary SCUBA gear, there is a regulator at the tank which restricts the air flow if the pressure in the hose approaches a predetermined maximum. There is a second regulator at the mouthpiece which permits air flow only if the pressure in the mouthpiece is below that of the surrounding water.